# Junit Unit tests not running in docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a spring boot application, my junit unit tests run perfectly in IntelliJ when I run "mvn clean install", but when try to run them inside of a docker image, non of them actually run, I get that they are compiled, but they don't run.
here is the content of my docker-image:

```
FROM docker.xxxxx.com/oicp/standard/maven/amzn-maven-corretto8:latest AS build

USER root

ARG build
LABEL build=${build}
LABEL image=integration
ARG appVersion=local

COPY src /home/appuser/integration/src
COPY pom.xml /home/appuser/integration/pom.xml
COPY settings.xml /home/appuser/integration/settings.xml
COPY entry.sh /home/appuser/integration/entry.sh

WORKDIR /home/appuser/integration/
RUN mvn -f pom.xml dependency:go-offline
CMD mvn -f pom.xml clean package

CMD mvn test-compile
CMD mvn test
```

```
Compiling 11 source files to /home/appuser/integration/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ @@@@@ ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ @@@@@ ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/appuser/integration/target/test-classes
[INFO]
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-05T17:47:29Z
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Not sure that this is the source of the problem, but: ["*There can only be one `CMD` instruction in a `Dockerfile`. If you list more than one `CMD` then only the last `CMD` will take effect.*" (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: I wouldn't normally expect unit tests to be included in your image in any case.  I'd run the JUnit suite using host tools, before you `docker build` an image out of only the application.

Comment: I would suggest the same @DavidMaze but furthermore the question is why do you run `mvn clean package`, `mvn test-compile` and `mvn test`? Just use `mvn verify` that's all what is needed...

Comment: Very important quesiton: Which plugin version do you use because I see extreme old version maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 which is more than a decade old... check also the plugin versions.. ? Have you defined them in your pom file? Do you use a parent? Please show the full log output?

Comment: @Turing85 I tried with one CMD, got the same result. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: @khmarbaise the mvn cmd doesn't really matter, it doesn't see the tests anyway. thanks anyway!

Comment: @NaderKhalaila du you have a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github repository?

Comment: @Turing85 example of which code? This is a corporate code and unfortunatelyI can't share it. but what I can say is that it doesn't matter what I run, it runs perfectly in IntelliJ, but doesn't run inside the image.

Comment: We cannot help without a [MRE]. There are multiple possibilities that could cause this issue.

Comment: I saw in different places that it's actually possible to run unit tests inside of a container after building the image. @DavidMaze
in my case, my application is built also when building the image, so how can I run the tests before that. 
I have one container that will be deployed on jenkins and run on argocd, so can't do anything outside of it

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: A [mre] does not require to copy the full code, especially not company full code. On the contrary, it is supposed to contain as little code as possible. Also it should be directly here and not e.g. only a link to a github repository.

Answer (score 0):

You're having multiple CMD statements in your Dockerfile, however only last is getting executed instead this you can concatenate your CMD commands. Here is updated Dockerfile -

```
FROM docker.xxxxx.com/oicp/standard/maven/amzn-maven-corretto8:latest AS build

USER root

ARG build
LABEL build=${build}
LABEL image=integration
ARG appVersion=local

COPY src /home/appuser/integration/src
COPY pom.xml /home/appuser/integration/pom.xml
COPY settings.xml /home/appuser/integration/settings.xml
COPY entry.sh /home/appuser/integration/entry.sh

WORKDIR /home/appuser/integration/

# Run Maven to download dependencies
RUN mvn -f pom.xml dependency:go-offline

# Build the application
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package

# Run tests (this is typically not necessary if you are building the project with 'mvn package')
# RUN mvn -f pom.xml test

CMD ["mvn", "test"]
```

Please make sure your tests are located in standard Maven directory structure `(src/test/java)`.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, turned out its Junit version issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating Junit from 4 to 5
Now everything works perfectly.